# UnauthorizedAccessException on Public Desktop Folder with C#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I want to make a Shortcut and save into Desktop Public folder, but is throwing UnauthorizedAccessException with this code :

```
        WshShell wsh = new WshShell();
        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ALLUSERSDESKTOP")  + "\\App.lnk") as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;
        shortcut.Arguments = " some arguments";
        shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + "\\App\\to\\link\\app.exe";
        shortcut.Description = "Description";
        shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + "\\App\\to\\link\\";
        shortcut.Save();
```

This code is running on a Windows Services, any suggestions??

Help Plz =S

Comment: What user is the windows service running as?

Comment: Admin user privileges, on W10...

Answer (score 0):

After a while... i did it!!

All you need to do is add an App Manifest file to the project and add this line :

```
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

and thats all, i hope this can be usseful for someone...